# User Specific Pages -but only editable by admin?

Tags: routes, users

I couldn't figure out how to directly address my situation.

I've created a website and I would like to be able to create user accounts for my clients from which when they log in the main menu will have each users specific page. In that user specific page I'd like to have a user specific menu page/(index) to which other pages are linked, to be able to display another website/(iframe), (such as specific jobs for that particular client). I'll need to impliment this between now and a week or two.

I've looked at me aliases, couldn't figure it out. I currently have Access Control installed but that will only allow me to restrict pages based on authenticated or anonymous.

I'm looking for an automated backup solution as well if anyone knows about that.

I'm willing to do the work myself, but if you are someone competent, hit me up and we can talk about getting paid.

Thank You!!!